# Compact framework equivalent of traceview

Tags: compact-framework, mobile

My day job is using the compact framework but as a home/side project I'm starting to learn Android development.

Having seen Androids traceview (a visual profiling tool) does anyone know if there's anything similar for .net and the compact framework (version 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [EQATEC's call profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler).

Comment: That is indeed a very useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

[The Power Toys for .Net 3.5 Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c8174c14-a27d-4148-bf01-86c2e0953eab&displaylang=en) has a profiler called NETCF CLR Profiler.  That is the closest thing I know about -- but it doesn't give you quite as much as you get with Android's TraceView.